# How to use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader to create schema from an existing MySQL database?

Tags: class, schema, loader

I am trying to use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader to create schema from an existing MySQL database. I used the  make_schema_at method like this:

```
C:\xampp\perl\bin>perl -MDBIx::Class::Schema::Loader=make_schema_at,dump_to_dir:.\lib -e "make_schema_at('turboimmisoft::Schema', ['dbi::mysql::dbname=turboimmisoft', 'root', ''])"
```

where: turboimmisoft is the name of my database

I got the following error message:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm line 165.
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_connect(): You did not provide any connection_info at -e line 1
[download]
I am using ActivePerl 5.14.4 on Windows Vista and the path the the MySQL database is: "C:\xampp\mysql\data\". The path to perl.exe is: "C:\xampp\perl\bin\"
```

To connect to the MySQL database with DBI (not DBIx::Class), I use:

```
use DBI;
my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $database = "turboimmisoft";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password)   #, {RaiseError => 1
+, AutoCommit => 1}
          or die "Could not connect to database:$DBI::errstr";
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am new to DBIx::Class but I have been using DBI since 2007.

Do I have to create new folders in the DBIx::Class folder for the new schema?

Answer (score 0):

10 months late I realize, stumbled across this searching for something else. Your `make_schema_at` call is wrong.

```
make_schema_at( $schema, \%loader_options, [$dsn, $user, $pass] );
```

[make_schema_at](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader#make_schema_at) documentation

you are passing in an ArrayRef where make_schema_at is expecting a HashRef.

Try

> C:\xampp\perl\bin>perl
>   -MDBIx::Class::Schema::Loader=make_schema_at,dump_to_dir:.\lib -e "make_schema_at('turboimmisoft::Schema', { debug => 1 },
>   ['dbi:mysql:dbname=turboimmisoft', 'root', ''])"